# My View cannot resolve a class in a different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a seperate project to process Entity Framework data functionality.
My View needs to be strongly typed and use a class in that project.

However this line cannot be resolved in my view;

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SCD_Database.Models.Subcontractor>
```

Yet in my controller there is no problem

```
using SCD_Database.Models;

public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ListSubcontractors(int page = 1)
    {
        var list = Subcontractor.GetSubcontractors().ToPagedList(page, 20);
        return View(list);
    }
```

The odd thing is that I selected the class from the selection when I created the View.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are in a different namespace you have to add a using inside your view:

```
@using SCD_Database.Models
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SCD_Database.Models.Subcontractor>
```

If you are referencing a DLL and not from GAC then set *"Copy Local"* to `True` for your reference.

Comment: I tried that. I still get "Cannot resolve symbol SCD_Database"

Comment: @arame3333 You have the reference added to your project right? Also if you're including a dll and you're not referencing from GAC set "Copy local" to true for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that intellisense, or maybe resharper where not working properly.
The error message disappeared when I rebuilt the application.

Comment: Yeah, the razor intellisense is not so great!